# pandas require version xlrd 1.1.0 but styleframe should have xlrd 1.0.0. How to set it correctly, so that I need both styleframe and pandas?

Tags: pandas, xlrd, styleframe

```
### I tried to read excel, pandas.read_excel("excel_file.xlsx") where I got the error saying "ImportError: Pandas requires version '1.1.0' or newer of 'xlrd' (version '1.0.0' currently installed)" ###
```

1. Reinstalling xlrd.

   2. After when checked styleframe dependency tree, 
      --- styleframe:
      StyleFrame==2.0.4

      - colour [required: >=0.1.5, installed: 0.1.5]
      - jsonschema [required: Any, installed: 3.0.1]
      - attrs [required: >=17.4.0, installed: 18.1.0]
      - pyrsistent [required: >=0.14.0, installed: 0.15.3]

        - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 40.6.2]
      - six [required: >=1.11.0, installed: 1.11.0]
      - openpyxl [required: >=2.5, installed: 2.6.2]
      - et-xmlfile [required: Any, installed: 1.0.1]
      - jdcal [required: Any, installed: 1.4.1]
      - pandas [required: >=0.23.2, installed: 0.25.0]
      - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.16.4]
      - python-dateutil [required: >=2.6.1, installed: 2.8.0]

        - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.11.0]
      - pytz [required: >=2017.2, installed: 2019.1]
      - xlrd [required: ==1.0.0, installed: 1.2.0]
   3. From the style frame documentation, I could see that xlrd==1.0.0:
      (install_requires=['openpyxl>=2.5', 'xlrd==1.0.0', 'colour>=0.1.5', 'jsonschema'],)

Comment: This reads like a "bug" in StyleFrame (that they shouldn't be using ==1.0.0, either they should bump it or use a range... For the moment it looks like you can't use SyleFrame` and `pd.read_excel`

Comment: As a temp workaround you can first install StyleFrame then upgrade xlrd and pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temp workaround: first install StyleFrame then upgrade xlrd and pandas.

It will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: Thank you @DeepSpace. This worked. However is there any way to give the colors of cells/fonts as per our wish. Because I could see that you have given some set of predefined colors to use.

Comment: Yeah you can create Styler object and give it `bg_color` and `font_folor` with the color's hex value then set it to the relevant cells. Take a look at the advance example [link](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame#advance-example)